# Perform Dynamic Table Calculations in HTML - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table which allows the user to enter some values, either directly or from a select menu.

```
<form action="" method="">
<table id="scores" width="358" border="1">
<tr>
<th colspan="5">Activities</th>
</tr>
<tr class="header">
<td width="104">Activity</td>
<td width="163">Rating</td>
<td width="69">Hours Per Week</td>
<td width="163">Weeks Per Year</td>
<td width="163">Average Hours Per Week</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title"><input type="text" value=""/></td>
<td><select name="rating">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
  <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
</select></td>
<td class="title"><input type="text" value=""/></td>
<td class="title"><input type="text" value=""/></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title"><input type="text" value=""/></td>
<td><select name="rating">
<option value=""></option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
  <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
</select></td>
<td class="title"><input type="text" value=""/></td>
<td class="title"><input type="text" value=""/></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="title">Total High</td>
<td class="title" id="totalHigh"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="title">Total Moderate</td>
<td class="title" id="totalModerate"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><button class="copy"  value="Set Value">Submit</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to perform a couple of calculations as follows:

1. for each row I need to calculate the "Average Hours Per Week" which is simply the (Hours Per Week * Weeks Per Year)/52
2. for each row the user can select either "High" or "Moderate" for the Rating. I need to then calculate the total of the "Average Hours Per Week" for all rows where Rating = "High" and all rows where Rating = "Moderate".

I've spent the better part of today pulling out my last remaining hairs trying to get something working using jQuery which I'm a  newbie with. I've setup a jsfiddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/tZPDr/

which has a simplified version of the table. Would greatly appreciate any help about how to go about performing these 2 calculations dynamically as the user types.

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: This doesn't seem to be that difficult, but could you lay out a demo? That features the input, and where the output should go? (If you could update your JS Fiddle, with pre-filled fields, to show the inputs/outputs, that'd be awesome. Sorry if I'm not seeing something obvious =/ )

Comment: Thanks David, I've updated the JS Fiddle with some sample data and calculation results: http://jsfiddle.net/tZPDr/3/ There can be mutiple rows - the number of rows isn't fixed. I also need to round this to 1 decimal place. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Did a few tweaks, check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/tZPDr/1/). Rest you should be able to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this as user types, you need to bind onto `keypress` or `keydown`.

Example:

```
$('td.hours input').on('keypress', function() {
   //get  the values and calculate
});
```

Then choose you fields and perform the calculations. You can get the values like this

Example:

```
var hrs = $('td.hours input').val();
```